# multi pages in same decorator configuration file

Tags: java, decorator, sitemesh

I use decorator template with sitemesh and have a `decorators.xml` file like:

```
    <decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators"> 
    <excludes> 
        <pattern>/styles/*</pattern> 
        <pattern>/scripts/*</pattern> 
        <pattern>/images/*</pattern> 
        <pattern>/index.html</pattern> 
    </excludes> 
    <decorator name="layout" page="layout.jsp"> 
        <pattern>/*</pattern> 
    </decorator> 
    </decorators>
```

I want to add more decorators to this file. I must separate their patterns.

Is there any way without adding patterns for all pages one by one?

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution for this problem.
this xml filters pages top-down. so if you want to write a decorator for only a page, you must write;

```
<decorator name="layout1" page="layout1.jsp"> 
    <pattern>/page1*</pattern> 
</decorator>
<decorator name="layout" page="layout.jsp"> 
    <pattern>/*</pattern> 
</decorator>
```

so **layout.jsp** does not work for page1, it is filtered at first decorator.

Comment: I have created the similar pages with the different directories. but Sitemesh is not working instead it take from the mail layout file. What may be the issues ? `<decorators defaultdir="/Page/Decorators">
    <excludes>
        <!-- Exclude the specific page from the decorator -->
        <pattern>/index.jsp</pattern>        
    </excludes>    
    <decorator name="user" page="layoutUser.jsp">
        <pattern>*/User/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
    <decorator name="main" page="layoutMain.jsp">
        <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>`